# create-react-app cannot access global javascript object from app.min.js

Tags: jquery, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm using `create-react-app` boilerplate and implementing an admin theme for the layout. In `index.html` file, there is a `script` import from the theme asset like this:

```
<body>
  <noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
  </noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/global/scripts/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Inside that script, there's a global javascript object named `App` to manipulate the UI. And now, I want to call that object in my `React` code:

```
export const alertMessage = (options = {}) => {
  const defaultOption = {
    type: 'info',
    message: 'message',
    closeInSeconds: 5
  };

  if (ALERT_TYPE_CORRECT[options.type] != null)
    options.type = ALERT_TYPE_CORRECT[options.type];

  options.icon = DEFAULT_ALERT_ICON_MAP[options.type];

  App.alert(Object.assign(defaultOption, options)); // here
};
```

But, it throws an error:

```
./src/Commons/utils/index.js
Line 25:3:  'App' is not defined  no-undef
```

How to make this works? Should I access it with `window.App`?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use it with `window.App` as the compiler tries to find the variable in the file itself and `App` is your custom variable you are attaching to the window.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the index.html file? Is the script file above the root div? If so, you will be able to access it by using window variable.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the question with my `index.html` structure. It's below the root div. It works with `window.App` but I'm still curious how can this script `https://github.com/2000lux/reduxadmindashboard/blob/master/client/src/Commons/utils/index.js#L3` can access it without through `window` object?

Comment: I assume it's due to the webpack configuration.

Comment: Oh I see, but Im not using `webpack` in my cra boilerplate. Is it okay if I just use `window.App` instead?